# Intersecting cones for weighted Voronoi diagram - DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

I want to make a diagram (and also a `Graph` of the vertex + edge config) of the orthogonal projection of the intersections of a set of conical surfaces in order to create [weighted Voronoi diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Voronoi_diagram) as in these pictures:

[additively weighted Voronoi diagram (heights vary)](http://api.ning.com/files/sUaGbNovZrqTyvywLX9jjiUaxFn2LWVLYRlOvXhFhBRNLCUThHi3mUnvC-kQto3U9VyjxTKFImocYiIBGIU8OpDUsxe*EMsT/mw_voronoi.jpg)

[multiplicatively weighted Voronoi diagram (radii vary)](http://api.ning.com/files/U71ysJZxWyJDnBaoCNcgHnAKKCH1BVLWNHvGX*sAu92pMslmfuVMEkfHo427q5W1s3760teWU6Iww6*NoFUgq4J6TNj5nRZT/aw_voronoi.jpg)

I tried to do this using Mathematica's geometric regions tools but they're not working well for me. For example, here is some code:

```
(* Define a cone centred at x,y,z with radius r and height h \
by subtracting a disk from the boundary of a solid cone *)

cone[x_, y_, z_, r_, h_] := 
 RegionDifference[RegionBoundary[Cone[{{x, y, z}, {x, y, z + h}}, r]],
   TransformedRegion[Ball[{x, y, z}, r], 
   Function[{p}, {p[[1]], p[[2]], 0}]]]


(* Create a random set of cones sitting on the xy-plane*)

n = 3;

SeedRandom[123]

points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
heights = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}, n];
radii = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}, n];

cones = cone[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], 0, #[[2]], #[[3]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{points, heights, radii}];


(* Check discretize region for one cone*)

DiscretizeRegion[cones[[1]]]


(* Discretize union of intersections of cones *)

DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionUnion[RegionIntersection /@ Subsets[cones, {2}]]]
```

For the particular random seed `123`, `DiscretizeRegion[cones[[1]]]` outputs [image: output]

However it fails for most other random seeds. And then the next line has failed for every seed I tried (and does so quite slowly).

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** I hope to get this working nicely for about $n=60$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica seems to prefer implicit regions, you can get the cones easily enough:

```
cone[xc_, yc_, r_, h_] := ImplicitRegion[(x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2 == r^2 (h - z)^2/h^2 && 
z >= 0 && z <= h, {x, y, z}];
n = 3; SeedRandom[123];
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
heights = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}, n];
radii = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}, n];
cones = cone[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2]], #[[3]]] & /@ 
   Transpose@{points, heights, radii};
DiscretizeRegion[#, Method -> "RegionPlot3D"] & /@ cones
```

You can even get some kind of intersection with

```
intersect = BooleanRegion[BooleanCountingFunction[{2, n}, n], cones];
DiscretizeRegion[intersect, Method -> "Semialgebraic"]
```

though not without artefacts

If you just want to plot Voronoi diagram, better do it directly with:

```
cone[xc_, yc_, r_, h_] := 
  h - h/r Sqrt[(#[[1]] - xc)^2 + (#[[2]] - yc)^2] &;
Plot3D[Max@Through@cones@{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Plot3D]

```
DensityPlot[Ordering[Through@cones@{x, y}, -1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Density plot]

Comment: Thanks. This method doesn't seem to be effective though since it is giving an error for $n>4$ and is quite slow anyway. I'd like to have this working for larger, say $n=60$. Maybe using the Geometric Regions toolset is not the best way to about this?

Comment: Maybe a lower-level approach could be better? For example, plotting the cone arrangement with Plot3D and looking at the view ![from the top](http://s29.postimg.org/4bjb0f2if/Voronoi_Cones.png) the intersection diagram is visible from the lighting effect within the 3D graphics and the image is produced instantly even for a very large number of cones.

Comment: @AthanasiosEvangelou, you asked about Regions, if you just want to plot it, you can just plot it, I added some ways to do it